# User/Subject - specific LaTeX Customisation

Tags: feature-request

Would it be possible (and useful) for the site to maintain LaTeX preferences/short-cuts, similar to style files, attached to usernames or topics?

Or even better, to allow users to create a list of different "style files" which could be selected when answering any particular question. As an example, if a user wanted to write a long answer to a quantum mechanical question, they could select "Dirac-Notation" and then use handily created short-cuts like *\expectation{Operator}* or *\state{indices}*.

I think this would allow answerers to stop worrying about left and right brackets and pipes and various things: and therefore removing another barrier to giving fuller and clearer replies.

All comments welcome.

Comment: We've looked into this in the past, and I _think_ the conclusion is that it's not possible, or at least not easy enough that the SE team considers it justified. But don't take my word on that (yet).

Comment: See dupe above for how it can be done. But SE has ignored it, so possible they don't want to consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I partially resolved this problem using an external LaTex compiler (console, whatever it's name, I'm using Lyx actually, which is free, open source and simple to use) to write my posts in SE before submitting them. It does not entirely solve the problem in the sense that the further edits are more complicated to implement that way though...